# Do I need a visa to work in Romania if I have a Bulgarian residence/work permit?

Tags: visas, europe, romania, bulgaria, working-visas

Does a non-EU citizen (Turkish) with a Bulgarian residence-work permit need a visa to work in Romania?

I have been working in Bulgaria for a time and I got a better job in Bucharest. So am I able to work in Romania without having any visa issues?

Comment: You will need a new work visa, but the question should be asked on Expatriates Stack Exchange. This site is for short-term travel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you received your working permit from the Bulgarian Government. A Bulgarian work permit is not valid in Romania. You must apply for a permit to the immigration office in Romania, and the permit can be obtained on a limited period and only for one employer, but also with other several conditions that need to be satisfied including the fact that the employer must have all the situation in green condition and as for the employee, he has to be medically healthy, must have knowledge and experience to practice a certain job and there is no Romanian citizen or European citizen that can occupy the position.

Comment: Hello andreihandrari

I am appreciated for your comment. I have one more other question. If Bulgaria enters the Schengen Agreement, am I going to be able to work anywhere in Europa holding only a Bulgarian residence-work permit? 

Thank you in advance ...

Comment: I'm assuming you would have to apply for a new one, since that was issued by the Bulgarian Government and not the European Union, but don't take my word for it, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. Let's see how it will go in future :)